# Error: HDL Compiler : 1660 : Procedural assignment to a non-register big_mant is not permitted, left-hand side should be reg/integer/time/genvar

Tags: verilog

In the lines wherever I try to do the assignment of value, the above error pops up. Please tell me what's the mistake and guide me with the corrected code snippet.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module big_small (


input [3:0] mant_A,
input [3:0] mant_B,
input [3:0] exp_diff,
input exp_diffsig,
input mant_diffsig,
output [3:0] big_mant,
output [3:0] small_mant
);




always@(*)

if (exp_diff == 4'b0000)
begin
big_mant <= (mant_diffsig)? mant_B: mant_A;
small_mant <= (mant_diffsig)? mant_A: mant_B;
end


else
begin
big_mant <= (exp_diffsig)? mant_B: mant_A;
small_mant <= (exp_diffsig)? mant_A: mant_B;
end


endmodule
```

Comment: `left-hand side should be reg/integer/time/genvar` - the left hand side of the `<=` assignment must be one of those four types. Is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says `left-hand side should be reg/integer/time/genvar` - in other words, on the line indicated, the left hand side of the `<=` assignment must be one of those four types.

Your left-hand side is declared as `output big_mant` (same goes for `output small_mant`) which are of type `wire`. You cannot do a procedural assignment (assignment inside an always statement or initial block) to a wire type as the error message has told you.

Change the two outputs to `output reg` types if you wish to use them as the left hand side of a procedural assignment statement.